# Master page error: The page as one or more <asp:Content> (...)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a master page and afterwards a web form with master page. After creating the web form with master page it gives me the following error:[image]

This is the code from my master page (Principal.master)

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Principal.master.cs" Inherits="AgereWP.Principal" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 52px;
            height: 52px;
        }

        .auto-style3 {
            width: 384px;
            height: 111px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <h1 class="header">

            <img alt="" class="auto-style3" src="Imagens/Webp.net-resizeimage.png" /></h1>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="leftcolumn">
                <div class="card">
                    <h2>
                        <img src="Imagens/icons8-upload-24.png" />
                        Upload</h2>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <div class="card">

                    <h2>
                        <img src="Imagens/icons8-download-24.png" />
                        Download</h2>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <h2>Rodape</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the code from my web form with master page (default.aspx)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Principal.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="AgereWP.Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

I've tried to change the ContentPlaceHolderID, run it with the default ContentPlaceHolderID, removing the `<!--->` comments... and can't figure it out why is this error occuring. Apparently it does not allow me to create any other contentholder other than the `head` and `ContentPlaceHolder1` but I can't understand why.

Note: I'm using visual studio community 2019

Comment: remove on contentPlaceHolder from master page, the second one.

Comment: I can do that but can't I use multiple ContentPlaceHolders? I already know that the ```ContentPlaceHolder2``` is causing this problem but why? Shouldn't I be able to use it?

Comment: just think about this that how will you declare that the page you are loading into master page must be loaded into the second content place holder?? when we are dealing with master pages then there must be only one CPH at master page body. I think you are trying to make something dynamic. You can share with us may be we can find some other way than using multiple CPH.

Comment: This worked fine for me when I copied your code into a new project. Maybe something else in your project is interfering?

Comment: @SkyeMacMaster Yeah you're right, something must be interfering with that project because I tried a dummy code with the same number of ContentPlaceHolders on a new project and it worked fine.